# What exception to throw when a property or a method being accessed is temporarily unavailable?

Tags: java, .net, exception

What exception to throw when a property or a method being accessed is temporarily unavailable (as it makes no sense in the current state of the object)?

Following is a semi-illustrative example coming into my mind, don't take it too serious, try to consider the question itself if you get it.

A `fraction` class having `numerator` and `denominator` read-and-write properties and `quotient` read-only property. If `denominator` does not equal 0 then `quotient` is to return `numerator`/`denominator` else it is to throw an exception saying that the property value is not defined/available for the current state of the object (please don't offer `ArithmeticException` or `DivideByZeroException`, the question is not about arithmetics, it is closer to the finite state machines subject).

Another example can be an object of a class doing some complex calculations in a parallel thread and providing the result as a field - it can throw the exception if the calculations are not complete yet.

I am interested in answers for Java and .Net platforms.

Comment: why don't create your own IvalidStateException or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`java.lang.IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.