# What is an appropriate Java exception to throw for when a requested element does not exist?

Tags: java

I would like to throw an exception for when no element is found when querying a database. My database integration returns `null` and for a variety of reasons, I'd rather thrown an exception. Here is pseduocode for my situation:

```
Object result = db.query(statement);
if (result == null) {
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

However, I'm not sure what an appropriate exception to throw for a situation like this is, where the requested item does not exist. The ones I have considered:

- [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

  - > Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.
  - The method was given a valid argument, it just didn't exist in the database. So this seems like a poor use.
- [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

  - > Thrown by the `nextElement` method of an `Enumeration` to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.
  - The name sounds right, but the description says that it's for enumerations, which is not what I'm using here.
- [NotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html) (Java EE)

  - > A runtime exception indicating a resource requested by a client was not found on the server.
  - The description says that it's for a resource requested by a client not being found on the server, which isn't what I'm doing here.

So what is the appropriate exception to thrown in a situation where the requested element does not exist? Are there others out there that I'm not considering?

I would prefer an exception in core Java. I'm willing to make my own exception if there is no appropriate exception, but would prefer an existing exception if it exists so as not to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit:** I do not believe that this is primarily opinion based because each exception has a documented purpose. I am wanting to know which exception's documented purpose is closest to the situation I am looking for.

Comment: Upgrade to Java 8 javadoc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Because their descriptions are now different.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Would you be willing to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Since it's data coming from SQL, maybe an [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) should suffice. Though it might be an idea to extend that and add your own stuff to it. That way you could do a casting check to confirm it was a missing value rather than any other `SQLException`

Comment: Why not use your own exception?

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is an appropriate exception already. I am willing to create my own though if there is nothing.

Comment: This is inherently dependent on what it means for that exception to be thrown. Did the invoked method expect such an argument that resulted in an incorrect return value? Was the argument valid but it turns out that there is no result? This is rather vague and depends strongly on the contract of your code. Write what the code truly _means_. All answers are possible and opinion-based without that.

Comment: I think you should reconsider having an exception thrown. Exceptions are used for **exceptional**, abnormal cases. If you expect the situation where a nonexisting member is passed to the method to be normal, then you really shouldn't use exceptions. Just my opinion.

Comment: My 2 cents: your are in a custom usecase that calls a custom Exception. A database that fires null in theory has a wrong syntax or something like that. In your case means "0 results" or "not standard error", so a not standard error can have a custom Exception, otherwise just check if null or 0, no need an exception.

Comment: the comments **prove** this is too broad, opinion based, too localized and it is also a duplicate of the exact same question many times over.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson So how can I fix this question to make it better?

Comment: vote to delete it; that will make it better since it is **off-topic: opinion based**  all the opinions in the comments **prove it**. You really need to do some research on how exceptions are supposed to be used, you are not using them correctly if you are asking this question to begin with. Nothing in your question indicates an *exceptional* case.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't agree. Returning null could be an exceptional case in the application business logic, meaning the DB is corrupted or a coding bug.

Comment: @m0skit0 - that is like your opinion, man

Comment: If the query is supposed to return a collection, I would return an empty one. If the query is supposed to return a single object, I would return an Optional.

Comment: Similar: [What exception to throw when a property or a method being accessed is temporarily unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8117463/642706)